# bUnit Unit Test not working as expected with Async

Tags: unit-testing, blazor, bunit

I have the following Unit Test:

```
 [Fact]
    public void FetchStudents_Rendered_Test()
    {

        var testData = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Sample Name",
                Email = "sample@email.com",
                Phone = "123456789",
                Address = "Sample address"
            }
        };

        var mockDbSet = Mock.Of<DbSet<Student>>(dbSet => dbSet.AsQueryable() == testData.AsQueryable());

        DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "StudentsTest")
                        .Options;

        var mockDbContext = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>(options);


        using var ctx = new TestContext();
        ctx.Services.AddSingleton<IStudentsService>(new StudentsService(mockDbContext.Object));

        // RenderComponent will inject the service in the WeatherForecasts component
        // when it is instantiated and rendered.
        var cut = ctx.RenderComponent<FetchStudents>();

        // Assert that service is injected
        Assert.NotNull(cut.Instance.students);
    }
```

The StudentService looks like below:

```
public class StudentsService : IStudentsService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public StudentsService(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<List<Student>> GetStudentsAsync()
    {
        return await _db.Students.ToListAsync();
    }

}
```

When I run the unit test I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncEnumerable<BlazorStudentApp.Data.Models.Student>'. Only sources that implement 'IAsyncEnumerable' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.'

I have tried setting up the DbSet in multiple different ways, but I keep getting the same error.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you mocking a `DbContext` instead of creating a mock implementation of your `IStudentService`? You're not testing your `StudentService`, so you should mock it.

Comment: Can you should me an example?

Comment: Mock `IStudentService`. Have the mock implementation of `GetStudentsAsync` return whatever data you're testing with. Then test your component accordingly.